# Workaround to add className to Fragment in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am trying to create a stateless component in React with the sole purpose of acting as a reusable wrapper. I am also using CSS Modules because I want to have fully modular CSS.

The thing is I don't want to add unnecessary elements (and even more so `<div>`s), but instead I want to use React's Fragments.

Now, the problem I have is Fragment (at least for now) do not accept classNames. So if I try this:

// In Wrapper.js:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import styles from './Wrapper.css'

const wrapper = (props) => (
    <Fragment className={styles.wrapper}>
        {props.children}
    </Fragment>
)

export default wrapper
```

In (for example) Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Navbar.css'
import Wrapper from '../../Layout/Wrapper'

const navBar = (props) => (
    <nav className={styles.navBar}>
        <Wrapper>
            This is the site's main navigation bar.
        </Wrapper>
    </nav>
)

export default navBar
```

Now I can of course, use a div instead of the Fragment, but is there any other workaround to avoid using unnecessary markup, of which I am totally unaware of?

Comment: Why not use a `<div>` instead of a fragment? I haven't used fragments yet but it is my understanding that they are just for wrapping a group of components in JSX but doesn't actually render a wrapping element in the dom. Where as a div will actually wrap the elements in a div. Correct me if I'm wrong though...

Comment: If you want a className, this className will have to apply to an element, no ? And Fragments do not render any element, so you can't use a className with it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM. - https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

What Fragments tries to solve it's the unnecessary dom elements but this doesn't mean that Fragments will replace `div` entirely. If you need to add a `className` there, it's clear that either you add a dom element in this case another `div` or add the `className` to its parent.

Answer (score 17):

Using `Fragment` means not adding an extra node to DOM.

If you want to assign a `className` to a node then you'll have to use `div`.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a css file and import it inside your App.js
2. Create a higher order component withClass.js like below

```html
    import React from  'react';
    
    const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
        return props => (
            <div className={className}>
                <WrappedComponent {...props} />
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default withClass;
```

3. Import your hoc too.
4. In your App.js write something like below

```html
    <React.Fragment>
        <p>Some JSX code here</p>
    <React.Fragment>
    
    export default withClass(App, classes.App);
```

I created .App class inside my css file and imported it so that i can use it later with `classes.App`. This way you can apply any css class that you create inside your css.You can use the same wrapperComponent to wrap every component you have, by simply importing it and changing export in your component. You just have to make classname of your choice and use it in export statement of your component. When you write props with spread operator(...). All the props from your component will be passed to this wrapperComponent.

Answer (score 0):

So the only thing the `Wrapper` / `Fragment` does is acting as a CSS wrapper over the children of `nav`?

I am not very experienced with css-modules, but if I wanted to avoid an extra DOM node just for the className I'd use something like this to get both classNames applied to `<nav>`:

```
import React from 'react'
import navStyles from './Navbar.css'
import wrapperStyles from './Wrapper.css'

const navBar = (props) => (
    <nav className={`${navStyles.navBar} ${wrapperStyles.wrapper}`}>
       This is the site's main navigation bar.
    </nav>
)

export default navBar
```