# Full-height column using Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a React project using Tailwind CSS and I want the sidebar to take the full height below the logo and have the links to the left with a specific width, but it is not working

[image: front end look]

**profile.jsx**

```js
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "../App";
import ProfileView from "./profileView"

function Profile() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const msg = location.state?.mes;
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(msg === undefined ? "" : msg);
  const [cancel, setCancel] = useState(msg === undefined ? "" : "X");
  const [name, setName] = useState(
    msg === undefined
      ? "h-0"
      : "h-10 flex justify-around items-center bg-green-200 text-black"
  );
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);

  function handleClick() {
    setSuccess("");
    setCancel("");
    setName("h-0");
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className={name}>
        {success}
        <button onClick={handleClick}>{cancel}</button>
      </div>
      {state.logStatus ? (
        <div className="h-full">
        <ProfileView />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="h-96 bg-red-200 flex justify-center items-center text-3xl font-bold">
          <div>You need to login in order to view your profile!</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

**profileView.jsx**

```js
import { Component, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../App";
import AdminProfile from "./adminProfile";
import StudentProfile from "./studentProfile";
import TeacherProfile from "./teacherProfile";

function ProfileView() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
  <div className="h-full">
  {state.identity.id === "admin" ? (
        <AdminProfile />
      ) : state.identity.id === "teacher" ? (
        <TeacherProfile />
      ) : (
        <StudentProfile />
      )}
  </div>
  );
}

export default ProfileView;
```

**studentProfile.jsx**

```
import { SiGoogleclassroom } from "react-icons/si";
import { FaHouseUser } from "react-icons/fa";
import { MdGrade } from "react-icons/md";
import { MdManageAccounts } from "react-icons/md";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const side = [
  { title: "Class", icon: <SiGoogleclassroom />, link: "/class" },
  { title: "Dormitory", icon: <FaHouseUser />, link: "/dormitory" },
  { title: "Grade", icon: <MdGrade />, link: "/grade" },
  { title: "Account", icon: <MdManageAccounts />, link: "/account" },
];

function StudentProfile() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-[#2f4050] text-white box-border w-1/4 h-full">
      {side.map((val, index) => {
        return (
         
            <Link to={val.link} key={index}>
              <div>{val.icon}</div>
              <div>{val.title}</div>
            </Link>
         
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default StudentProfile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section is not taking the full height because you haven't defined a height for the parent of the following component (which is react fragment)

```html
<div className="h-full">
    <ProfileView />
</div>
```

So giving a value for the height of the above component would get your job done.

**Note: Since a fragment is the parent of the above component, you have to replace it with a JSX element.**

```html
<div className="h-[100vh]">
    <div className="h-full">
        <ProfileView />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: Since a fragment is the parent of the above component, you have to replace it with a JSX element.why we need to do that is this a rule?thank you it works but is making a scroll bar, what i want is just to fit the left place.

Comment: but for that using h-[353px] instead of h-[100vh] will work,after calculating the px sizes of all elements from top to bottom,but for the future i will retain to % values.

Comment: Hi @ayex check out this post on why we need to change the fragment to a JSX element https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070103/14953535